# Firebase - Understanding the Denormalized Data Structure

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am finalizing the structure of my Firebase and want to be certain I'm going forward with the simplest and most-scalable design early on.

**Requirements**

- A user can have many favorite teams
- A team can have many users who have favorited it (favoritees)

Here is my current data structure

```
firebase
--team-favoritees
--teams
--user-favorites
--users
```

Most posts I have read on Firebase structuring have had more of this kind of structure

```
firebase
--teams
----favoritees
--users
----favorites
```

However, I've also read Firebase should be as denormalized as possible which is why I've structured my data to have one-less nested node.

That being said - 
is there any drawback to my design? Wouldn't updating multiple nodes at the same time be easier if I didn't have to dive one extra node deeper, potentially pulling unwanted records for a simple transaction? Is one design recommended over the other?

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: This question is pretty vague. I think it's a good attempt though. To answer correctly, we would need to understand your use case; what does *update multiple nodes at the same time* mean? How does your data interact? What kind of queries do you need to run. All of those make each use case different. For example,*A team can have many users that favor it*. To what end? What do we need to know? You could query all of the users that have a certain favorite team. Or you could read in a user list from a teams, users node. More information would help.

Comment: I say, there is only one "table" required for the favorites, as one would represent it in a traditional SQL database: by adding a table users_to_teams, which only represents the keys of that particular relationship.

Comment: @syslogic firebase is a nosql database, so it doesn't carry the idea of relation tables that an SQL database would implement. When dealing with nosql it's better do denormalize data even if it introduces some redundancy all for the sake of more efficient read operations/less IO

Comment: @KuraiBankusu thank you for educating me, while I'm aware of that, while obviously you did not understand what I was trying to tell ...instead of stuffing all the keys into one "table" (while you actually suggested to creating lots of duplicates), one can stuff all the keys into their own "table" and simply lookup by the keys... there is no advance in storing a key to key relation in both directions, while one has to maintain both... your structure is fundamentally flawed, because teams probably do not have favorites (one would assume).

Comment: Teams have "favoritees", or users who have favorited them, if that wasn't clear

Comment: have thought about it... if it would be teams & players (some kind of league), I probably could make sense out of it. while only because it's noSQL does not mean one cannot use keys - or wrapper methods, which resolve for keys. most common might be to add the keys (of teams & players, each nested) into the user's node, who favorites them - referring to the other structure.

Comment: for easy lookup, one can add methods, which add/remove 2 keys at once... eg. user follows a team, gets the team's key added - while the team gets the user's key as follower added; ordinary there is not much advance in linking in both directions, while in this situation, it would help when trying retrieving the data again (eg. wanting to list all the other followers of a team).

Answer (score 1):

`transaction` has specific meaning (it's a method of it's own).  If you mean `update`, I know [they show how](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) to send multiple 'commands', if you will,

```
  // Write the new post's data simultaneously in the posts list and the user's post list.
  var updates = {};
  updates['/posts/' + newPostKey] = postData;
  updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;
```

I imagine this 'stacking of commands' into a single update object is supported with the other methods though (such as `transaction`).

Regarding the data structure / denormalization they provide [a specific example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#fanout) for "data that scales" that I follow.